# How to round off float number to 2 decimal numbers in azure logic apps?

Tags: azure, rounding, azure-logic-apps

In azure logic app I convert kilogram to to pound, I need to round off that result to two decimal numbers.

[image]

```
Expression : mul(float(variables('total_weight')) , 2.20462262185)

Result :  1.102311310925
Expected Result : 1.10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now, there is still no generalized rounding solution in Logic Apps. However you need build solutions specific to your data.

Here is an approach you could round decimals to two for display purpose.

```
if(contains('56789', substring(string(variables('math')),4,1)),substring(string(add(variables('math'),0.01)),0,4),substring(string(variables('math')),0,4))
```

This way will return the string format, you could add `float()` to return float number. I test twice with `2.20462262185` and `2.20562262185`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

My workaround for rounding the numbers is to use [`formatNumber()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#formatNumber) function with [fixed-point format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-fixed-point-f-format-specifier). So your code would look like this:

```
formatNumber(mul(float(variables('total_weight')) , 2.20462262185), 'F2')
```

The format string in the last parameter - 'F2' - where 2 specifies the decimal places. Two decimal places are the default for the fixed-point format, so you can also just use 'F'.

I can see that  you're using it on a property of another object variable, so just like George mentioned you'd need to wrap the result in `float()` function:

```
float(formatNumber(mul(float(variables('total_weight')) , 2.20462262185), 'F2'))
```